# The ♦ character is formatted to look like the moderator diamond on the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

Whilst using the SE Android application last night I noticed I had an upvote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29558231/1317805) I wrote a while back. This answer features the ♦ character which is the same character used to distinguish moderators. Rather than treating this as a regular ♦ character, it gives it the same larger, orange style that the moderator diamonds have, both in text and within a code block:

[image: Example]

---

This affects the listing screen as well as question titles:

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

Comment: This also happens on the iOS app, but not in question titles: http://i.imgur.com/OdnTV7p.png

Comment: How do these characters ♠♡♢♣ ♤♥♦♧ look to you? (Those are the Unicode playing card suits from U+2660 to U+2667; the mod diamond is the second to last one, U+2666 Black Diamond Suit.)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly it doesn't matter how the diamond reached the contents, it's about how the device itself renders it.

Comment: The mod diamond is just a Unicode character appended to every mod's name. SE has applied custom styles (or a custom font, or something) to make that diamond look fancy for the mods, but that also affects anywhere else the same character is used.

Answer (score 2):

On my phone, I see a shaded black diamond:

> [image: Screenshot]

This indeed looks the same as the diamond after moderators' user names does on my device. It also matches the appearance of the other black playing card suits in my comment above. I thus conclude that tha SE Android app isn't actually doing anything special about the ♦ character, but just letting your device render it as usual. It just happens that your Android device is choosing to render it as a fancy colored (or, in my case, shaded) "emoji-style" character, rather than as just a flat black geometric shape. The exact appearance probably depends on your Android version and any customizations your device vendor may have made, including the set of installed fonts.

Anyway, perhaps the real issue here is that the app *should* be rendering the real mod diamond as some custom icon, instead of just displaying a Unicode U+2666 Black Diamond Suit character and letting the OS render it any way it likes?

Comment: A bit more testing: let's see how the Unicode playing cards look like with [VS15 (U+FE0E)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Emoji_versus_text_presentation) appended ♠︎♡︎♢︎♣︎ ♤︎♥︎♦︎♧︎ versus with VS16 (U+FE0F) ♠️♡️♢️♣️ ♤️♥️♦️♧️. On systems that properly support Unicode emoji, and have emoji-style versions of the playing card suits available, the first set of suits should be rendered in "text style" and the second (if possible) in "emoji style". Alas, it seems that, at least on my Android phone, there is no visible difference.